# Question on rotating a square at its diagonal

Tags: geometry

> A square sheet ABCD when rotated on its diagonal AC as its axis of rotaion sweeps a

[image: Diagram]

1. Cone
2. Spindle
3. Cylinder
4. trapezium

The right answer is Spindle. But how.
Because in the question they didn't mentioned B and C as fixed. Could any one explain. if possible upload a diagram

[Refer question number 41](http://www.jagranjosh.com/articles/ctet-solved-question-paper-ii-2011-1311406324-1)

Comment: I'm not sure how you're supposed to justify the answer; it's obviously not a cone, not a cylinder and not a trapezium.

Comment: Don't have much of a choice . Because it is not a trapezium , cylinder or cone. So the answer would be spindle.

Comment: If you only sweep the triangle $ABD$, then you get a cone, so you can see that you get 2 cones with the same base.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "they didn't mentioned B and C as fixed."

Comment: Ctet exam question. I think the question is of poor quality.

Comment: The question is fine. You rotate the square this way, you get a spindle. There is nothing ambiguous about it.

Comment: It doesn't mention BC as fixed, because it is AC that is fixed. When it says rotated on the axis AC, it means that is the fixed axis of rotation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is more of English than math.

Two cones on a common base or a double cone.. can be called a spindle.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

Here is the solid that we get when rotate around $AC$.

Two cones with the same base (a cicle with diameter $BD$).